# Delete all records from one table where they match criteria from two (or more) tables

Tags: mysql

Consider the following:

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM 
`table1`,`table2` 
WHERE `table1`.`RemoteID` = `table2`.`ID` 
AND `table2`.`UserID`=1
```

How can I change it from a `SELECT` to `DELETE` from table1 where these records match? It must *only* delete from table1, not table2

In less specific terms,  I want to delete all records from table1 where they match some criteria of both tables (discretely and relatively)

Comment: you can use subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` with sub query

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE `table1`.`RemoteID` IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM table2
    WHERE `table2`.`UserID`=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Delete
from `table1`
where `Id` in
(select `table1`.`Id` 
from `table1` t1, `table2` t2
where t1.`RemoteID` = t2.`ID`
  AND `table2`.`UserID` = 1)